# How to use RedirectToPage with a default handler that requires a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using Razor Pages on .Net Core 2.2 and I have the following handler defined on an Index page:

```
 public async Task OnGetAsync(string legalDocSubType)
```

and I am trying to use RedirectToPage to go to this page with:

```
return RedirectToPage("./Index", "legalDocSubType", PublishRecord.LegalDocSubType);
```

which produces this URL portion:

> /Publishing?handler=legalDocSubType

which is wrong, I wanted:

> /Publishing?legalDocSubType=Module

So I don't understand what I have done wrong? I want to be able to redirect to this index page and pass my querystring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might it be this?

```
return RedirectToPage("./Index", new { legalDocSubType = "Module" } );
```

Comment: Yeah I think this is close. return RedirectToPage("./Index",  new { legalDocSubType = "Module" }); is doing it.

Comment: awesome! I updated my answer. Can you accept if it's correct?